# How do I switch which Vue component I display in my app depending on whether it's build in Cordova or Electron?

Tags: cordova, vue.js, electron

I have a Vue.js app. For mobile apps I build the app with Cordova and for Desktop clients I build it with Electron. 
In some cases I want my application to react differently depending on whether it's build for Cordova or Electron.

If I want to show the `CordovaStartPage`-component with Cordova and `ElectronStartPage` with Electron, how do I have to change:

```
export const routerOptions: RouterOptions = {
    routes: [
        {
            path: "/startpage",
            component: StartPage
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You could set an environment variable in your build process and test for it when choosing a component?

Answer (score 0):

To detect electron, I would just wrap the call in an if checking:

`window && window.process && window.process.type`

There is also:

`process.versions['electron']`

Hope this helps.